# POST запрос через JS

Tags: html, javascript

Всем привет, у меня есть JS:

```
$('.form_test_form').on('submit', function () {
var $form = $(this);
var submitParams = $form.serialize();
var url = $form.attr('action');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    processData: true,
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    data: submitParams,
    headers: ({"Auth-Secret": $("input[id='authpass']").val()}),
    success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
    }
});
});
```

С помощью него я отправляю пост запрос из  нескольких `<input>` после нажатия на `<input type="submit">`.

Проблема моя заключается в том, что после нажатия на кнопку меня перекидывает на новую страницу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.form_test_form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно ещё с помощью **return false;**, который отменит событие не только у текущего элемента, но и у всех родительских элементов.

```
$('.form_test_form').on('submit', function () {
    //...
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Однако `preventDefault` гораздо православнее. Христос не одобряет `return false`.